# Chrome extension running javascript on a page error: Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Manifest.json file I have:

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'"
  }
```

In my popup.js file, I'm creating dynamic code in a string called: **cde**

For brevity, I've hard coded it to just show an alert:

```
    cde = "alert('hi');";

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        if (tab) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                function: (cde) => {
                    console.log(cde);           
                    eval(cde);
                },
                args: [cde]
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('Script executed successfully.');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        } else {
            console.error('No active tab found.');
        }
    });
```

I can see that the code (cde) is getting passed to the page, as the console.log shows ***alert('hi');***

However the console also gives this error:

```
alert('hi');
VM143:3 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript
because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*".
```

I've tried searching for the error, but can't find a solution that works.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do either to the manifest.json file, or to update my Javascript which runs the code, in the ***chrome.tabs.query***

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: The code injected by executeScript is a "content script", so extension_pages CSP doesn't apply to it. You can't use eval in it unless you switch to the unsafe MAIN world, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949953).

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to answer.  Instead of building my javascript dynamically, through loops etc and passing the code as a string to the page, I've moved it to within the executeScript section, and built it line by line in there. So I no longer need to use eval().  Thanks again!