# How to run user scripts (dynamic js) in a packed chrome extension MV3 (Chrome web store)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I need to run a script entered by user in every tab user opens. Is there a way to do this in a packed chrome extension which would be accepted by the web store.

**Note** : This has already been answered for unpacked extension [Chrome Extension: How do I inject a script that the user provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70949491/chrome-extension-how-do-i-inject-a-script-that-the-user-provided)
I need to know if its even possible at this point to do this in a **packed** extension. i.e. one which would be hosted in chrome web store

Comment: It's physically possible in a packed extension, but the web store will probably disable your extension if they find this in their review of your code. There is no other solution yet, until the userscripts API is implemented and shipped.

Comment: is there any official announcements from chrome on when the userscripts API will release for MV3 . @wOxxOm.
We have an extension that is on hold for dynamic user scripts and MV3 extensions will be removed from chrome web store 2024 January (as mentioned in timeline)

Comment: They are still working on implementing it and didn't release anything yet.