# General Manifest V3 eval() disabed workaround

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, bookmarklet, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to make a bookmarklet to Manifest V3 chrome extension converter (V2 already exists) but becuase `eval()` is disabled I can't find a way to convert any given bookmarklet to a functioning extension.

I've tried `Function()`and storing the bookmarklet code in a separate file locally but neither worked.

Comment: It's disabled by design. There are ways around this restriction e.g. via `sandbox` in manifest.json, but what is the actual eval code in that bookmarklet? Maybe it can be rewritten.

Comment: @wOxxOm It sounds like he's trying to make a generic converter that works with any code. So requiring someone to manually rewrite the bookmarklet misses the point.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes. That is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: See [Chrome Extension: How do I inject a script that the user provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70949953)